# Child table dependent on parent table

Tags: postgresql

consider the following tables:

```
create table parents (
  id text primary key, 
  child_one text not null, 
  child_two text
);

create table children (
  id text primary key,
  parent_id text references parents(id) on delete cascade,
  label text
);
```

My intention is two-fold:

1. I want to require that `parent` *must* have `child_one`, and can *optionally* have `child_two`
2. I want to say that if `parent` is deleted, I want this to cascade down to `children`.

In order to support "1", I added columns in `parents`:

```
  child_one text not null, 
  child_two text
```

In order to support cascading deletes, I also include the `parent_id` in `children`:

```
  parent_id text references parents(id) on delete cascade,
```

The main problem with this approach, is that now I can't guarantee at the db level that `child_one` and `child_two` will always exist. I also don't like that I am duplicating data (`children` does not really need to have `parent_id`).

Is there another way I could model the data, so that these two constraints are maintained?

Comment: 1) If you have a row in `parents` `child_one` and `child_two` will exist and `child_one` will have value as it is `NOT NULL`. 2) If you want the FOREIGN KEY cascading delete you will need the `parent_id text references parents(id) on delete cascade`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redundancy is no problem if consistency is guaranteed with foreign key constraints. In fact, that is the canonical way to do it.

Create a redundant unique constraint on `children` that will serve as target for a foreign key constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE children
   ADD UNIQUE (parent_id, id);
```

Now you can enforce consistency with deferred foreign key constraints on `parents`:

```
ALTER TABLE parents
   ADD FOREIGN KEY (id, child_one) REFERENCES children(parent_id, id)
          DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
   ADD FOREIGN KEY (id, child_two) REFERENCES children(parent_id, id)
          DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

You need to insert the two or three rows in a single transaction, with the `parents` row first, so that there are no constraint violations.

This will work fine with the cascading delete from your foreign key.